# Remove newline from unix variable

Tags: sed

I have a variable whose value is found using sql query.

I want to remove the new line character from that variable since I want to concatenate this variable with the other. Below is the code:

```
dt=`sqlplus -s user/pwd@servicename <<EOF
set feedback off;
set head off;
select  replace(to_char((sysdate-7),'YYYYMonDD')||'_'||to_char((sysdate-1),'YYYYMonDD'),chr(10), '') from dual;
exit;
EOF`

echo "test $dt"
```

Answer (score 49):

If you are using `bash`, you can use Parameter Expansion:

```
dt=${dt//$'\n'/} # Remove all newlines.
dt=${dt%$'\n'}   # Remove a trailing newline.
```

The following should work in `/bin/sh` as well:

```
dt="${dt%
}"                # Remove a trailing newline.
```

Comment: Just FYI, when you're using `${var//a/}` you don't need to use last `/`, `${var//a}` will do exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you all.Below thing worked dt=${dt//$'\n'/} # Remove all newlines.

Comment: For those curious in the full syntax, here is a link to the bash documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: `dt=${dt//[$'\n\r']/}` if you need to remove Carriage Returns as well

Comment: I tried to remove **all trailing newlines** via `${dt%%$'\n'}` and `${dt/%$'\n'/}`, but why both failed?

Comment: @Mr.Míng: `${dt%%$'\n'}` still removes a single newline as there's no wildcard. You can use `shopt -s extglob ; s=${s%%*($'\n')}` though.

Comment: It works, thank you very much! @choroba

Comment: Use `dt=${dt#$'\n'}` to trim newline at the beginning / leading newline.

Answer (score 27):

Sounds like you need "tr", something like:

```
 echo ${dt} | tr -d '\n'
```

man tr for detail, as usual

Comment: simple and readable +1

Answer (score 3):

This work on Linux (bash):

```
dt="$(echo "$dt"|tr -d '\n')"
```

On Linux, or other systems with GNU's date utility, this also works to get that value for dt: (without involving Oracle...)

```
dt="$(date -d 'yesterday' +%Y%b%d)_$(date -d '7 days ago' +%Y%b%d)"
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding sqlplus. If you're on a system without GNU date but you have Tcl: `echo 'puts [clock format [clock scan "-1 week"] -format %Y%b%d]_[clock format [clock scan yesterday] -format %Y%b%d]' | tclsh`

Answer (score 0):

from the [Oracle sqlplus manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699247)

**SET PAGES[IZE] {14 | n}**
Sets the number of lines on each page of output. You can set PAGESIZE to zero to suppress all headings, page breaks, titles, the initial blank line, and other formatting information.

so add a `set pagesize 0` to your script to avoid a heading blank line.

for most of my scripts I use the settings in the following code piece of code:

```
dt=`sqlplus -s user/pwd@servicename < < EOF
set feedback off
set pagesize 0
set trimout on
set trimspool on
set linesize 300
set echo off
set verify off

select  replace(to_char((sysdate-7),'YYYYMonDD')||'_'
||to_char((sysdate-1),'YYYYMonDD'),chr(10), '') from dual;
exit;
EOF`

echo "test $dt$dt"
```